# How to show calendar only on icon click?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker

I use `bootstrap-datepicker-1.9.0` in my application. Recently customer requested that calendar should display only when user clicks on the calendar icon. The current code works for the entire input group. Here is my code exampleL

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        setDatepicker("input-group.date");
});

function setDatepicker(className) {
        $("." + className).datepicker({
        format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
        orientation: "bottom auto",
        autoclose: true
    });
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group m-1">
  <label class="font-weight-bold" for="begin_dt">Begin Date:</label>
  <div class="input-group date">
    <span class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span></span>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="begin_dt" id="begin_dt" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to display date-picker only when user clicks on the calendar icon. I still didn't find the way to accomplish that. If anyone knows the way to achieve this please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use an `onclick` function to get the parents of the clicked icon and show the datePicker there.

We will need to use `.parent()` and `attr` to get the actual `classname`. As the class name has a space in it. You can replace it with the `.`

I have added end date as well to reflect that the function works on both dates.

Edit: To make sure that after clicking on the icon the datepicker doesnot show on the input focus: We can use `showOnFocus: "false"`

Run snippet below it only works on the icon click.

```js
function setDatepicker(_this) {
  //Get the parent class name so we can show date picker
  let className = $(_this).parent().parent().parent().attr('class')
  //Remove space and add `.`
  let removeSpace = className.replace(' ', '.')
  $("." + removeSpace).datepicker({
    format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
    orientation: "bottom auto",
    autoclose: true,
    showOnFocus: "false"
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group m-1">
  <label class="font-weight-bold" for="begin_dt">Begin Date:</label>
  <div class="input-group date">
    <span class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar" onclick="setDatepicker(this)"></i>
      </span>
    </span>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="begin_dt" id="begin_dt" value="">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group m-1">
  <label class="font-weight-bold" for="begin_dt">End Date:</label>
  <div class="input-group date">
    <span class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar" onclick="setDatepicker(this)"></i>
      </span>
    </span>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="end_dt" id="end_dt" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tested your example above. This is still not behavior that I want. After click on the calendar icon and select the date value is populated in the input field. That's expected behavior and works fine. After that if I click in the input field I see that bootstrap date-picker is displayed. That is not behavior that I want. The date picker should only show when user clicks on the calendar icon.

Comment: @espresso_coffee Answer updated and working as you wanted.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Question, why this is accepted as valid date format mm/dd/yyyy here is example: `07/09/20`. Thank you

Comment: That is US date format. Just change format to ``dd/mm/yyyy`` for this way. Example: ``format: "dd/mm/yyyy",``

Comment: That's the issue. I set the format to  `mm/dd/yyyy`  but if I enter date like this `07/07/2020` it's accepted as valid. That's a bug. That date is not valid. You can see the format in my original post.

Comment: @espresso_coffee Its a datepicker you can not enter date manually and expect it to work like date picker. It will not work like that.

Comment: Ok, I got that. What is the solution for that issue?

Comment: @espresso_coffee Its not considered as an issue! There is no direct solution to what you are asking. Date pickers are meant to come in handy to not type manually. Thats the main goal of a datepicker is.